# How can I install apps again after forgetting my "content filtering" PIN in Google Play?

Tags: downloading

I am unable to download certain applications. I can't remember my content filtering pin number. I would like to get help with  resetting my pin number.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to remove the PIN by going into *Settings > Apps > All > Google Play Store*, and press on *Clear Data*.

Not that this will not have any effect if you chose to confirm every purchases with your Google account password.